# Drawing a curved domain in Matlab using "meshgrid"

Tags: matlab, mesh

I have solved a PDE's problem and I have the matrix with the values of the solution. The problem is that I don't know how to represent in the domain the solution. The domain is a rectangle with this vertices:

A(0,0)
B(1,1)
C(0,2)
D(-1,1)

I want to use 'meshgrid' without needing to evaluate every single point of the grid by myself. Someone can give me some help?
Thanks!

Comment: your _solution matrix_ must have a dimension. Each point of the solution correspond to a domain coordinate. You just have to specify this coordinates to meshgrid (you won't have to re-evaluate the solution for these point).

Comment: My problem is how to evaluate correctly every single (xi,yi) of the grid, when the grid is not rectangular. I already have the solution, the grid is the problem.

Comment: The domain you are defining (by 4 points) looks like a normal square to me. You would need more points to define a "curve". For the domain between your 4 points, just `meshgrid` a normal square then apply 45 degree transformation on all the points `X,Y`.